# Android Sharing Resources / passing resource information between activities

Tags: android, android-activity, view, resources, imageview

Hello Friends I am facing a new Problem while developing an android app. I am just a newbie to android app development. I have started developing an app where i have a array of images inside an activity which when clicked should open in another activity

Here Is My Layout

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnCount="3"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" 
android:background="#99CC00">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sample_2"
    android:onClick="viewImage" />
</GridLayout>
```

Here is My Code....

```
public void viewImage(View v)
{
    System.out.println("Function Running");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this , ViewFullImage.class);

    intent.putExtra("name", v.getId());

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Here is My Other Activity

```
public class ViewFullImage extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_fullimage);

    ImageView imgview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int data = intent.getIntExtra("name", 0);

    imgview.setImageResource(data);

}
}
```

But When i Run The App, it Stops after i Open The Activity on clicking image
Any Help Would be appreciated

Comment: "I am facing a new Problem" what is the problem?

Comment: Whenever an App crashes, post the log here to get better help ;)

Comment: okkk the problem is i have a imageview in one activity and when i click on that imageview the image should open in next activity....any idea how this can be implemented......

Answer (score 0):

```
public void viewImage(View v)
{
    System.out.println("Function Running");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this , ViewFullImage.class);

    intent.putExtra("name", v.getId());

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Is v the view ! null ? if it is you would get an NPE that crashes the app.
Also, are both registered activities in the manifest ?

Comment: the activities are registered in manifest. the activity start but the image is not being displayed in the next activity. BTW crash problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `view.getId()` for retrieving image resource identificator. `getId()` returns widget id. Instead of this, you can use following code for your first activity:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView.setDrawableResource(<your drawable resource id>);
imageView.setTag(<your drawable resource id>);
...
public void viewImage(View v)
{
    System.out.println("Function Running");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this , ViewFullImage.class);

    intent.putExtra("name", (int)v.getTag());

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: thanks Roman Zhukov for your answer but I have another problem now i will be passing image name from first activity and want to create an image view from that name in the other activity can u please help me sort out this problem

Comment: And what is the problem? How to create Bitmap from image path?

Comment: yup thats the problem " how to create imageview from the image name passed from first activity????? "